# Multi-line commands in ray debug

Tags: python, ray

How do I run multi-line commands inside the Pdb debugger brought up by `ray debug`?

For example, running two nested for loops:

```py
for loader in loaders:
    for data, labels in loader:
        # do something
```

I tried `inteact` -- the console is not responsive.  Anything I type after that gets no response.  Also, I'm not able to cleanly get out of it other than a ^C.

I tried single-line code like the one below:

```
(Pdb) i = 0
(Pdb) for loader in loaders: for data, labels in loader: i = i + 1
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am able to do simple list comprehensions like so:

```
len([1 for loader in loaders for data, labels in loader])
```

But I'm looking ways to do more than this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think the problem is. Can you explain more what doesn't work as expected? Do you know how to use Pdb in general?

Comment: Yes, I've used Pdb before.  1.  I can `interact` with vanilla Pdb, but not when doing it through Ray.  2. I tried code like: `for loader in loaders: i = 0; for data, labels in loader: i = i + 1` -- this resulted in a `*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.  Will update the post.

Comment: In single line: [data, labels for data, labels in [loader for loader in loaders]]